# Laravel GET API with url params not entering proper function?

Tags: api, get, laravel-7

I recently took over a existing Laravel + Vue.js project and I am working with a Laravel 7 API server and have defined a few GET endpoints. However when I try to pass URL params, the behavior becomes unexpected. An example is below:

`api.php`:

```
Route::get('ping', function() {
    return ['status' => 'success', 'data' => 'DATA']; 
}); 

Route::get('ping-arg/{arg}', function ($arg) {  
        return ['status' => 'success', 'data' => $arg]; 
});
```

POSTMAN:

`localhost:8000/api/ping?XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM`  =>  Returns 'DATA' as expected

`localhost:8000/api/ping-arg?arg=100&XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM`  => returns some fallback HTML page

Any info on why this may be happening? I'm new to Laravel and banging my head on this for the last few days. Thanks in advance!

Comment: its because you have not passed parameter arg to URL ,

Comment: do you mind clarifying? my URL to access the endpoint is: `localhost:8000/api/ping-arg?arg=2` which defines arg=2.

Comment: localhost:8000/api/ping-arg/100?XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM

Comment: that URL still returns the same fallback.

Comment: clear cache and try .it should work